# How exactly was Aunt May related to Peter Parker?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

In the Spider-Man universe, how exactly was Aunt May related to Peter Parker's parents?  Was she related to him on his mom's side or dad's side?  Also, what happened to Peter's parents so that he lived with them when he was six years old?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Ben Married to Ben Parker. Dad's side. Also, plane crash.

Comment: Look up [Peter Parker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Parker) or [Aunt May](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aunt_May) on Wikipedia, follow the links to [the parents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_and_Mary_Parker).

Comment: General reference isn’t a close reason anymore. Voting to reopen for great justice.

Comment: @amaranth Hey, congrats on 3k rep!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aunt May was his aunt by marriage.  Ben was the brother of Peter's father.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Ben

> Ben Parker was born in Brooklyn, New York. He trained to be a military
>   police officer. He spent time as a singer in a band. He had known his
>   future wife May Reilly since their high school days, but she in turn
>   was naively interested in a boy who was involved in criminal
>   activities. When he came to her one night and proposed to her on the
>   spot, Ben was there to expose him as a murderer, and to comfort the
>   heart-broken May when the boy was arrested. Their relationship evolved
>   into love, and they enjoyed a happily married life. When Ben's much
>   younger brother Richard Parker and his wife Mary were killed in a
>   plane crash, Ben and May took in their orphaned son Peter and raised
>   him as their own.

Sources:

- The Amazing Spider-Man #519
- The Amazing Spider-Man #600 (2009)